# Pop() and append() to next row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In this spreadsheet, I have a row with all the employee data, with values coming from another table; In order to create the layout requested, I need 3 rows per employee, each row starting with the |1|,|1.1|,|1.1|, I found some code here that allows me to append two rows to every row of data, but no idea how to move the |1.1|,GTF,'100' to the next row, and then, |1.1|,PPA,'15' to the next one.

This is what i have:

|1|,'900','04000','0000','0','0000','0','11','0','S','A',|1.1|,GTF,'100',|1.1|,PPA,'15'
|1|,'986','01000','0000','0','0000','0','14','0','S','A',|1.1|,GTF,'110',|1.1|,PPA,'30'
|1|,'1046','01000','0000','0','0000','0','14','0','S','A',|1.1|,GTF,'120',|1.1|,PPA,'45'

And what Im looking for is to look like this:

|1|,'900','04000','0000','0','0000','0','11','0','S','A'
|1.1|,GTF,'100'
|1.1|,PPA,'15'
|1|,'986','01000','0000','0','0000','0','14','0','S','A',
|1.1|,GTF,'110'
|1.1|,PPA,'30'

```
    function insertRows() {
  var startRow = 1;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Prenom");

  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow());
  var sheetData = sourceRange.getValues();

  var numRows = sourceRange.getNumRows() - startRow;
//  Logger.log(numRows);

  for (var i=numRows; i > -1; i--) {
    if (sheetData[i].join("")) {
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(i + startRow, 2);
    }
  }
}

Which leaves me with two empty rows. ty
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your showing values. All values are put in a cell? Or, for example, each `|1|,'900','04000','0000','0','0000','0','11','0','S','A',|1.1|,GTF,'100',|1.1|,PPA,'15'` is put to a cell? Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Hi, please consider providing a screenshot to clarify how is the data structured.

Comment: Correct, everything is joined in a cell,

Comment: from:                                                                                         ={ArrayFormula(join(",", {"|1|"},char(39)&(({Semanal!A4})&char(39)), char(39)&{TEXT(COUNTIF(Semanal!D4:R4,"F")&"000","00000")}&char(39), char(39)&(({{"0000"},{{"0"}}})&char(39)), char(39)&{"0000"}&char(39), char(39)&(({"0"})&char(39)), char(39)&{COUNTif(Semanal!D4:R4,"<>f")}&char(39), char(39)&(({COUNTIF(Semanal!D4:R4,"v")})&char(39)), char(39)&(({"S"})&char(39)), char(39)&(({"A"})&char(39)),{"|1.1|"},{"GTF"},char(39)&(({Semanal!V4})&char(39)),{"|1.1|"},{"PPA"},char(39)&(({Semanal!W4})&char(39)) ))}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split the cell value every time `|1.1|` is found. There are several ways to do this. For example, you can combine [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and in the sample below.

After you have done that, use [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to overwrite the original data.

#### Code sample:

```
function insertRows() {
  var startRow = 1;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Prenom");
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow());
  var sheetData = sourceRange.getValues().flat();
  sheetData = sheetData.map(cell => {
    const array = cell.split(",");
    const outputArray = [];
    let index = 0;
    while (index >= 0) {
      index = array.indexOf("|1.1|", 1);
      if (index !== -1) section = array.splice(0, index).join(",");
      else section = array.join(",");
      outputArray.push(section);
    }
    return outputArray;
  }).flat().map(row => [row]);
  sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheetData.length, sheetData[0].length).setValues(sheetData);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
function separate() {
  const s = `|1|,'900','04000','0000','0','0000','0','11','0','S','A',|1.1|,GTF,'100',|1.1|,PPA,'15' 
  |1|,'986','01000','0000','0','0000','0','14','0','S','A',|1.1|,GTF,'110',|1.1|,PPA,'30'
|1|,'1046','01000','0000','0','0000','0','14','0','S','A',|1.1|,GTF,'120',|1.1|,PPA,'45'`;
  let r = s.match(/([^']+[^|]+)/g);
  Logger.log(r.join('\n'));
}

Execution log
12:02:55 PM Notice  Execution started
12:02:55 PM Info    ||1|,'900','04000','0000','0','0000','0','11','0','S','A',
|1.1|,GTF,'100',
|1.1|,PPA,'15' 
  
|1|,'986','01000','0000','0','0000','0','14','0','S','A',
|1.1|,GTF,'110',
|1.1|,PPA,'30'

|1|,'1046','01000','0000','0','0000','0','14','0','S','A',
|1.1|,GTF,'120',
|1.1|,PPA,'45'
12:02:56 PM Notice  Execution completed

function separate() {
  const s = `|1|,'900','04000','0000','0','0000','0','11','0','S','A',|1.1|,GTF,'100',|1.1|,PPA,'15' 
  |1|,'986','01000','0000','0','0000','0','14','0','S','A',|1.1|,GTF,'110',|1.1|,PPA,'30'
|1|,'1046','01000','0000','0','0000','0','14','0','S','A',|1.1|,GTF,'120',|1.1|,PPA,'45'`;
  let r = s.match(/([^']+[^|]+)/g).map(e => [e]);
  let sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(1,1,r.length).setValues(r);
}
```

Comment: This looks good in the console, but if I try it in the spreadsheet, no changes can be seen, only in the console looks like has been changed, thanks though.